# python: How to compare elements within one list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the minimum value in a list using a for loop but I'm not getting the right answer.

This is what I am doing:

```
xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]

for i in xs:
    if xs[i]< xs[i+1]:
        print(i)
```

edit: sorry i should've said this earlier but I'm not allowed to use the min function!

Comment: Iteration over a list returns its items not indexes.

Comment: How about using the `min` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `for` loop , then use following method

```
xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]
minimum = xs[0];
for i in xs:
    if i < minimum:
        minimum = i ;
print(minimum)
```

Without loop , you can use the `min` method

```
minimum = min(xs)
print(minimum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `min` method:

```
xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]
print min(xs)
```

This outputs:

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a for loop ?

Just use:

```
xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]
print min(xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you intend to find successive elements that are in lesser to greater order.  If this is the case then this should work

```
for i in xrange(len(xs)-1):
    if xs[i]< xs[i+1]:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]
>>> print min(xs)
#Prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without a for loop and without `min()` using the built-in function [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
minimum = reduce(lambda x, y: x if x < y else y, xs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
    xs=[5,3,2,5,6,1,0,5]
    minvalue=xs[0]      #Assuming first value in xs as minimum value
    for i in range(0,len(xs)):
        if xs[i]< minvalue:     #If xs[i] is less than minimum value then
            minvalue=xs[i]      #minmumvalue=xs[i]
    print(minvalue)             #print minvalue outside for loop
```

Output:
0

Comment: Thry that with `xs=[2,0,2]` or even `xs=[2,0,3]`.